# How to skip some changes before release branch

Tags: git, git-flow

I had git history like this

```
  o  [release]
 /
----o0---o1---o2---o3---o4 [develop]
```

and then,I want release new version now, but I want skip o1 and o2 commits... because they are unfinished features, so, how to?

Comment: If they are unfinished features, why are they merged into the develop branch?

Comment: There are many reasons, maybe replan the release schedule, maybe developer mistake, anyways, just have some can't  to release futures..

Comment: In which case, I think cherry picking the commits that you did want onto the release branch would be the only course of action.  See here for more information: http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up/cherry-picking-explained.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on your graph the release branch does not have any of the commits o0-o4. They are all on the develop branch.

If you want to start a release branch without o1 and o2 here is a solution

```
git rebase <sha of o0> -i
```

Now you can move the commits around

Your log would look something like this

```
----o0---o3---o4---o1---o2 [develop]
```

If the moving worked you can start a release from o4